Reshaping a data table
I have a data table (Excel) with the following headers:  "Date", "Bob", "Joe", "Jane".  The data below the data headers would be "1/1/2025", 0, 0, 0; "1/2/2025", 1, 1, 1; "1/3/2025", 1, 1, 1.  The date indicates the day of the week, the number indicates whether a person will be working that day (1, 0).



Date
Bob
Joe
Jane




1/1/2025
0
0
0


1/2/2025
1
1
1


1/3/2025
1
1
1



I need to transform the table so that the headers are "Date", "Name", "On/Off".  e.g.   "1/1/2025", "Bob", 0; "1/2/2025", "Bob", 1; "1/3/2025", "Bob", 1; "1/1/2025", "Joe", 0; "1/2/2025", "Joe", 1; "1/3/2025", "Joe", 1; "1/1/2025", "Jane", 0; "1/2/2025", "Jane", 1; "1/3/2025", "Jane", 1.



Date
Name
On/Off




1/1/2025
Bob
0


1/1/2025
Bob
1


1/1/2025
Bob
1


1/2/2025
Joe
0


1/2/2025
Joe
1


1/2/2025
Joe
1


1/3/2025
Jane
0


1/3/2025
Jane
1


1/3/2025
Jane
1



The date value comes from the "Date" column, the name comes from the column, header, and the "On/Off" value comes from the data under the person's name.
The problem I am running into is that the NAME field in the new table is the header name of the old table
Hope this makes sense... Thanks in advance.

Can you show your input and desired output tables using Markdown tables; or using Excel to Markdown, [edit] your tables in text format into your existing question.

And and welcome to S.O. Please note that this is a not a free code writing service. That said, if you can show us what you have tried and explain the problem you are facing with your attempt, we'll be happy to take a look at help out. Also, description of data is never as clear as an actual sample. Consider using a table instead.

I use brute force to get it into the shape I want.  (Cut and Paste, Cut and Paste, etc...)

Current Shape
Date                                 Bob  Jane Joe  Fred
Wednesday, January 24, 2024 1 1 0 0
Thursday, January 25, 2024 1 1 1 0
Friday, January 26, 2024 1 1 1 0
Monday, January 29, 2024 1 1 1 1
Tuesday, January 30, 2024 1 1 1 1
Wednesday, January 31, 2024 1 1 1 1
Thursday, February 1, 2024 1 1 1 1

Desired Shape:
Date                          Name     On/Off
January 24, 2024       Bob        1
January 25, 2024       Bob        1
January 26, 2024       Bob        0
January 24, 2024       Bob        1
January 24, 2024       Bob        1

The problem I am running into is that the NAME field in the new table is the header name of the old table.

To read your data from Excel into Python, you'll want to use the following lines of code:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("path_name.xlsx")

This reads in the library most used for tables of data, pandas, and reads in the data from the file into a variable called df, which stands for dataframe.
Then to transform as appropriate, you can do:
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars="Date").rename(columns={"variable": "Name", "value": "On/Off"})

I'll explain the code so you can learn for yourself how to use it in future. pd.melt is a way of changing the format of dataframes. Other methods include df.stack, df.unstack, and df.pivot. Frankly, I can never remember which does what, so I just try them all until something gives me what I want the dataframe to be transformed into.
Setting id_vars="Date" just means that the date column is left alone rather than being transformed, while the other columns (the ones with the people's names) are transformed.
Then I rename the newly transformed columns using .rename({...}) and include a dictionary of the column names I want to replace. This gives me a dataframe that looks like the following:
|  Index|     Date    | Name | On/Off |
|-------|-------------|------|--------|
| 0     |    1/1/2025 | Bob  | 0      |
| 1     |    1/2/2025 | Bob  | 1      |
| 2     |    1/3/2025 | Bob  | 1      |
| 3     |    1/1/2025 | Joe  | 0      |
and so on.
I can then write this out to a CSV using:
df.to_csv("new_filepath.csv", index=False)
and that will write out the table to a new CSV without the index column, just as in your example. I hope that all makes sense!
